# Do status effect particles still show while the player is invisible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

**Will other players still see the particles from a player that drank a Potion of Invisibility?**

Comment: perhaps make your description a little more different than your title. In this case it's hard to do but its a good practice for future inquiries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's easily detectable and also you will be outlined when hit by certain arrows.

Comment: Umm.. I meant only the bubble particles. I didn't mean anything about the Spectral Arrows, since I know what happens if you are hit. I wanted to know this for Factions gameplay, in order to make interesting raids.

Comment: They will still see you. I thought my answer was too short ;) so I added a line.

Comment: But is there any way to hide the particles or something?

Comment: Not that i know as far as I'm concerned it's impossible for a vannila player.

Comment: Cosmic PVP <(Factions Server) has custom enchantments there is probably one out there.

Comment: I found a video but it requires the access to command blocks and seeing as this is for factions I doubt it will help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUsyE9cnggg

Answer (score 1):

The particles are visible unless the server has a plugin for it. You could also hope that the other players have gone into settings, and turned particles to none, which should disable them for their screen.